# CSV treatment using VBA - Seperator / Local setting issues

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm having trouble with CSV treatment in VBA:

1. I've got 1 input CSV file that need to be exported in 2 different CSV files, renaming certain columns and deleting others
2. Agents using the macro can't change local setting

I've got this code:

```vb
Dim fileBt As String
fileBt = SequoiaPath & Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1) & "/BT/NipBtSearch.csv"
            
FileCopy Path & Filename, fileBt
Dim Wbt As Excel.Workbook

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fileBt, DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True
Set Wbt = ActiveWorkbook

Debug.Print Wbt.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

Wbt.Close True
```

Don't mind it's optimization, I've been testing for hours now and it's kind of a mess.

PS: The computer are set to French, so I'm guessing my default separator is `,`.

*Output:*

NipBtSearch.csv is well formed, using correctly the semi-colons separator.
`Debug.Print Wbt.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value` gives me the whole line

```
N° Dossier;Intitulé du dossier;N° Accès produit;Objet de l'accès produit;Domaine;Date d'initialisation;Heure d'initialisation...
```

If I try to change the value of A1, it breaks everything in my new CSV, I'm guessing because line 1 now has only one column.

**So, as I was saying, I'm really struggling with this, I feel like I'm missing how to treat my CSV as a workbook with this range issue**

Comment: Are you 100% certain that it's a semi-colon? There are other characters that look *extremely* similar so there could be an encoding issue somewhere...

Comment: Your code shows you trying to _open_ the file directly - have you tried _importing_ it instead (as that might afford you more options) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try [opening the CSV as workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) using the options Delimiter= ";" and Local=True/false to check if it returns the expected output. Something like `Set Wbt = Workbooks.Open(pathtofilename, , , , , , ,,";", , , , ,True)` should work

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns i've tried with ur solution, i can edit as i wanted (with range) but, when I close the file (with wbt.close), the semi-colums change to commas like this : `Test,Intitulé du dossier,N° Accès produit,Objet de l'accès produit,Domaine,Date d'initialisation`

I absolutly need it to be semi-colums, do u have any ideas of how to force it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom the output concatenating the values with your delimiter semicolon.

I made a fake origin source CSV dataset like this called `csvfile.csv`

[image]

```
Sub tets()
Dim WBsource As Workbook
Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim FileSource As String, NewFileDestiny As String
Dim FullData As Variant


FileSource = "C:\Temp\csvfile.csv"
NewFileDestiny = "C:\Temp\newcsvfile.csv"

Set WBsource = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileSource, , , , , , , , ";", , , , , True)

With WBsource.ActiveSheet
    '<---do whatever operations you do with data--->
    
    .Cells.Replace "Value", "DummyText"
    
    '<---end operations you do with data--->
    
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    FullData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value 'take all data into array
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear 'delete everything
    
    'contatenate everything into Column A delimited by semicolon
    For i = 1 To UBound(FullData)
        'loop trough columns for each row of data and concatenate
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value & FullData(i, j) & ";"
        Next j
        
        'after concatenate all, delete last semicolon
        .Range("A" & i).Value = Left(.Range("A" & i).Value, Len(.Range("A" & i).Value) - 1)
    Next i

End With

Erase FullData 'delete to clear memory

'output to NEW csv to not alter original file!!!
WBsource.SaveAs NewFileDestiny, xlCSV

'close file
WBsource.Close False 'we already saved before, no need to redo


End Sub
```

After executing code I get a **new** CSV file like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for ur answer, it works well but only for the first line, the second one and all the others are stuck in the first column

Comment: What do you mean with *the second one and all the others are stuck in the first column*? Please, edit your original question and add what you get. Make sure you are using the code correctly.

Comment: I figured the issues, but i've got no idea of how to fix it, double quotes are added to every row but the first one when `WBsource.SaveAs NewFileDestiny, xlCSV` is executed.
My csv (when opened with text editor" looks like that :



`Title 1; Title 2; Title 3; Title 4;...
"Value1; Value2; Value3; Value4;..."
"Value1; Value2; Value3; Value4;..."
"Value1; Value2; Value3; Value4;..."`

Comment: That could be maybe any regional setting. Try with `WBsource.SaveAs NewFileDestiny, xlCSV, , , , , , , , , , True`. Also, maybe you need a different option for `xlCSV`. You can check different options at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat